# String[] with ints. how to get them out java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `String[]` with numbers like `{"12", "3", "5"}`.

I want to put these numbers in a `int[]`, like `{12, 3, 5}`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting here?

Comment: or are you asking some language feature/library function?

Comment: ofc i tried different things.. i will remember to post it next time.. i usually do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` loop is your friend here.

It will be done using a for loop and string to integer conversion by `Integer.parseInt(str)`.

I will not give any code here but as an algorithm, it will be:

```
1. Loop over string array.
2. For each string do
   a. Convert string to integer
   b. store it in integer array
```

Comment: @Swupper: Because `Darin Dimitrov` has given full code in his answer, there is no need to try for this. But will be better if you try yourself instead of copying someone's code for such things.

Comment: can't really use his code.. i'm making an IO system with java, where i save the input as an String[] and need to put this input in a int[] to make some other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a method that will do the conversion using the [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method on each element:

```
public int[] convert(String[] stringArray) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (stringArray == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int intArray[] = new int[stringArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Comment: @HarryJoy, indeed, I forgot returning the integer array. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes. You forgot to return `int[]` but now it's perfect... :)